# Vite + Solana wallet adapter

Tags: vite, solana

Does the WalletConnectButton work with vite? Everything is working fine for me in local dev, but after build and deploy the button is disabled and does not allow me to connect.

This behaviour is similar to what happens when a browser does not have a compatible wallet extension installed, but in this case, I have confirmed that the extension is installed and functioning in the browser.

```
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [nodePolyfills({include: ['stream'], globals: {Buffer: true, process: true}})],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        nodePolyfills({
          include: ['stream'],
          globals: {
            Buffer: true,
            process: true,
          }
        })
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

If anyone has experienced this of have any clues, please help!

Comment: FYI there is a dedicated Solana StackExchange which is the recommended place to ask questions about Solana solana.stackexchange.com